# Validating feature class name in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a model which creates feature classes based on the value in an attribute (using [Iterate Feature Selection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00400000000s000000)). It works fine as long the field values don't have spaces, punctuation marks, etc. but fails otherwise.

I know in a script I can use [`arcpy.ValidateTableName()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/validatetablename.htm) to convert *"C:\Big Kalzas!"* into a name that can be saved, *"C__Big_Kalzas_"*. How does one do the same in a model?

I tried Calculate Value with an expression as simple as `arcpy.ValidateTableName("%Field Name%")` do defining and calling a function, but it keeps evaluating to `1`.

[image: Model diagram, showing expression]

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that anything needing an import must be wrapped in a function:

```
validate("%Field Name%")

def validate(s):
    import arcpy
    return arcpy.ValidateTableName(s)
```

[image: example]

Comment: That's good to know and well explained.. +1 from me. I don't do much model builder as it's easier for me to do in python (now), normally I'd go searching for 'bad' characters and do multiple replace(BadChar,'_') statements. What does it return if the intended name exists? nothing wrong with the text but if the name already exists it can cause a script/model to fail (unless overwrite is on, but sometimes you *don't* want overwrite).