# Failure using inline variable %Name% as output file name in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, error-999999

I am using the following model to iterate through ASCII files and then use the reclassify tool:

[image: Model]

The model works very well if I use a generic name as the output file name, or even using an inline system variable (i.e. "*name%n%*" for example).

The problem comes when I want to use the inline variable *%Name%*, and I always get this error message. And I cannot find the origin of the problem.

```
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
The table name is invalid.
No spatial reference exists.
Failed to execute (Reclassify).
```

Comment: Does the %Name% variable begin with or contain an invalid character?

Comment: Most probably this is related to the workspace that you are trying to save your output. If it's a FDGB the whitespaces are not allowed, if it's a folder you need to specify a file extension, so on so forth. You may want to add a validate table name facility as in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151853/how-to-validate-a-feature-class-name-in-a-model

Comment: What is %Name% set to when you see this error?